# Marshal.PtrToStructure nested classes - parameterless constructor confusion

Tags: c#, marshalling

When marshalling to an instance of a class type, the type needs a parameterless constructor. Otherwise `Marshal.PtrToStructure` throws a `MissingMethodException`.
When marshalling to an instance of which contains nested classes they don't need a parameterless constructor.

See example code below. Marshalling works correctly, output is 1 2 3 4.
But why does the class `DummyNested` not need a parameterless constructor?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var buffer = new byte[10];
    buffer[0] = 1;
    buffer[1] = 2;
    buffer[2] = 3;
    buffer[3] = 4;
    Dummy dummy;
    unsafe
    {
        fixed(byte* bufferPtr = &buffer[0])
        {
            dummy = (Dummy)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(bufferPtr), typeof(Dummy));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", dummy.m_nested1.m_data1, dummy.m_nested1.m_data2, dummy.m_nested2.m_data1, dummy.m_nested2.m_data2);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private class DummyNested
{
    public byte m_data1;
    public byte m_data2;

    public DummyNested(byte data1, byte data2)
    {
        m_data1 = data1;
        m_data2 = data2;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private class Dummy
{
    public DummyNested m_nested1;
    public DummyNested m_nested2;

    private Dummy()
    {
        // This one is needed to get Marshal.PtrToStructure working, but why not on DummyNested type?
    }

    public Dummy(DummyNested n1, DummyNested n2)
    {
        m_nested1 = n1;
        m_nested2 = n2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well looking at the source for Marshal [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,f5afb57bc99ab27c) it looks like the implementation first calls an internal .Net method to create a default instance of the outer object (which requires a default constructor) and which will leave the inner class member references set to null. Then it calls an unmanaged `PtrToStructureHelper()` method which populates the rest of the class members (and which does not need to call any constructors, it seems).

Comment: Interesting, too bad that the source of `PtrToStructureHelper()` can't be sighted...

Comment: The field marshaller built into the CLR is a complicated chunk of code.  The parts that deal with embedded objects did get some comments from Don Syme, it doesn't look kosher.  Target .NET 4.0 or up and remove the [StructLayout] attribute on DummyNested and watch your program blow up spectacularly :)  This is unspecified magic.